# Camel send modified body to AMQ without modifying route's body

Tags: java, apache-camel, protocol-buffers

I have a rest-api which create a resource and send it on a AMQ queue.

I am using camel rest dsl and created the something like that :

```
rest("/api")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/test").type(Test.class)
                    .route()
                    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "direct:sendTestAmq")
                    .endRest()
from("direct:sendTestAmq")
            .convertBodyTo(TestProtos.Test.class)
            .marshal().protobuf()
            .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "amq:queue:test.queue");
```

When I call the endpoint, I get a base64 response corresponding to the protobuf binary.

I would like to get the Test.class json response.
I thought using "to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,...)" would permit that by not modifying the body.

This is another [example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e0cd821e2d12861dad65a661ac13042), the response is "After" and I wanted it to be "Before".

Does anybody knows how I could do it ?

Thanks

Comment: @ClausIbsen Wiretap is run in parallel am I right ? I'd like to wait for the message to be sent before sending the response.
I will have a status 200 event if an exception occures in the "direct:sendTestAmq" route

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ClausIbsen answer I found that multicast() also use a copy of the exchange for each route but instead of wiretap, it is not parallele per default.

I could achieve my goal by replacing `.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "direct:sendTestAmq")` by `multicast().to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "direct:sendTestAmq", "direct:mock").end()`.

Since multicast takes as an output the last route exchange, "direct:mock" is a route which does nothing but preserves the original body.